# Pythonic Regular Expression in a large text file for a tabular data

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text file that has a lot of console output. I am interested in all of the outputs that look like this (Output and Loss of Load):

[image]

The text file could have several of these paragraphs of interest distributed. What is the most Pythonic Regex to capture these values.

I may be trying to push the Regex here; but let's say, if there is a ######PROJECT Name: ABCD###### before each such table, but not immediately before, would it be possible to capture the project name too?

Comment: `grep -E 'OVERLOAD|LOSS OF LOAD' <file>` from console

Comment: Since the text file is 'large', is there any reason not to iterate by line? Then you just need 3 regexes for the project name, overload and loss of load (i.e. r'^OVERLOAD \\(%\\)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+))\s+'...etc.

Comment: ondra, Right.. I was looking to write less code as possible, so wanted to shove everything I wanted into one Regex. But the approach you suggested is the one I ended up taking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\#\#\#\#\#\#PROJECT\s+Name:\s+(?P<PROJECT_NAME>.+?)\#\#\#\#\#\#
.+?
(?P<OVERLOAD>OVERLOAD\(%\)(?:\s+\d+\.\d+){4}).+?
(?P<LOSS_OF_LOAD>LOSS\s+OF\s+LOAD\s+\(M\)(?:\s+\d+\.\d+){4})
```

#### Modifiers

```
sxg
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/gJ1mK4

Comment: Wish I could upvote and accept this answer more than once. Thanks! Regex101 is also awesome.

Comment: @LakshmanPrasad You can either start a bounty on the question or upvotes my other answers from my profile ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, a quick and dirty solution might be something like this...

```
projectname = ""
overload = ""
loss_of_load = ""
for line in data:
    if line.startswith("#######PROJECT"):
        projectname = line
    if line.startswith("OVERLOAD"):
        overload = line
    if line.startswith("LOSS OF LOAD"):
        loss_of_load = line
        print(projectname, overload, loss_of_load)
```